# unable to install rational software architect v8.5

Tags: eclipse, rational-rsa

I have got following exception while installing RSA V8.5, though I am going to install it again but curious to know what could be the reason behind it and How can we resolve it.

```
Error during "complete" phase:
CRIMA1084E: The singleton bundle "org.eclipse.epf.richtext_1.6.0.v20101028_0720" 
cannot be installed in this Eclipse configuration because there is a 
non-singleton bundle "org.eclipse.epf.richtext_1.5.0.v20080714-1745" 
that is already installed.
```

Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Are you installing by extending an existing Eclipse installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you chose to install RSA by extending an existing Eclipse installation. This message is telling you that RSA did not install a specific component because a component of the same type (`org.eclipse.epf.richtext`) already exists as a non-singleton.

This is likely to lead to problems. While IBM does provide you with the opportunity to extend an existing Eclipse configuration, it doesn't specifically state which Eclipse versions you're allowed to extend. It seems that your existing Eclipse installation is of an earlier version than the one provided by RSA itself.

You should do one of the following:

1. Not extend an existing Eclipse installation.
2. Ensure that the Eclipse installation you're extending is of the same version of the Eclipse installation shipped with RSA, to ensure compatibility. RSA ships with Eclipse platform version 3.6.3, which is Eclipse Helios.